# How can $|b_n| - |b| \le |b_n - b| $ imply $ ||b_n| - |b|| \le |b_n - b| $?

Tags: real-analysis

I was going through a proof in real analysis and I saw this implication. But I do not understand why it might be so. Is this an identity that is commonly used or is there some easier way to see it ? Because clearly if $ x \le y$ does not imply $|x| \le |y|$. The one above seems like a different case but I cannot figure out why it might be true.

Comment: Google *reverse triangular inequality*.

Comment: Thank you, it was an interesting read.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The implication would be reversed: the inequality $||b_n| - |b|| \le |b_n - b|$ implies $|b_n| - |b| \le |b_n - b|$. However, the inequalities $|b_n| - |b| \le |b_n - b|$ and $|b| - |b_n| \le |b_n - b|$ together *do* imply $||b_n| - |b|| \le |b_n - b|$. So perhaps the argument was missing the piece $|b| - |b_n| \le |b - b_n|$.

The thing to keep in mind is that the inequalities $x \le a$ and $-x \le a$ together are equivalent to the inequality $|x| \le a$.

Comment: Your help was very appreciated. I was in the middle of a proof concerning absolute convergence in Abbott S. Understanding Analysis. Your answer made eveything clear. Thank you.